# How to sync data between SQL Server and memory cache with service broker

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker

I want to sync data between SQL Server and memory cache with service broker.

For example:When I execute a SQL statement

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Customer(Email)
VALUES('abc@hotmail')
```

The cache will receive a message that database has a change and get the inserted value to sync cache data.

Also *delete* and *update* are necessary.

The goal is when database is changed,the cache will be notified and sync the data from SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: I want to monitor the service broker queue,while a message push,the cache can get the message as soon as possible.But dont know how to monitor

Comment: Are there any other solutions can been found ?

Comment: [Detecting Changes with `SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)